# How do I use lateral column alias reference properly in Amazon Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

According to [this](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/08/amazon-redshift-announces-support-for-lateral-column-alias-reference/), Amazon Redshift support lateral column alias reference, which to means I can reference a newly created alias given to a column within the definition of a table/view as long as said reference after the alias has been defined.

Yet when I run the following query:

```sql
(CASE
    WHEN (vht.current_email IS NULL OR vht.current_email = '')
        THEN vht.original_google_contact_email
    ELSE vht.current_email
 END) AS contact_email,
(CASE
    WHEN (vht.company_domain IS NULL OR vht.company_domain = '')
        THEN (SELECT split_part(contact_email, '@', 2))
    ELSE vht.company_domain
 END) AS company_domain
```

I get the following error:
`This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported yet.`

I would like to use `contact_email` to get `company_domain`, if possible. One of two things could be happening:

```
 1. Syntax error
 2. I don't understand the feature properly
```

My gut tells me it's the latter. Either way, I'd love to get some feedback that would help me solve this issue

Comment: Is this the entire query? There is no `select` clause to start with.

Comment: No. I just added the columns that were relevant to the bug I was facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the problem is coming from the `SELECT` in

```
THEN (SELECT split_part(contact_email, '@', 2))
```

Could you remove the SELECT? I don't think it's required.